# Is there a callback in Angular.js triggered after a ng-model binding is done?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

The question is clear I guess. I want to be informed after an `ng-model` binding is completed and the value is reflected to the DOM element.

I am aware that this can't be done for all `ng-model` bindings in a `document.ready` fashion but I would like to be informed at least for a particular element after DOM binding is done.

Why would I need it? To solve this problem with Bootstrap Material Design theme: https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/issues/194

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a **$watch** on the variable which is binded to ng-model

work around

**$timeout**  is executed when all the DOM manipulation is done , this assures that changes of your model have been reflected in the DOM

Comment: `$watch` is used for being notified on change of model's value. I want to be notified whenever the value is binded to DOM element. This doesn't necessarily requires a change of model's value.